# how do i change the sale badge text on a multi language wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So i want to change the sale badge text on a multilanguage site.
The english one is "Sale" and the German one is "Verkauf" which is auto translated by WPML.
I want "Sale" on both sites.

Ive tried

```
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', 'ds_change_sale_text');

function ds_change_sale_text() {
return '<span class="onsale">Custom!</span>';
}
```

but it wont work
How can this be done is it smth related with WPML?

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet instead or make your string untranslatable

```
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', 'ds_change_sale_text');

function ds_change_sale_text($text) {
    $current_language = apply_filters( 'wpml_current_language', NULL );

    if ($current_language === 'de') {
        // If it's German, return 'Sale'
        return '<span class="onsale">Sale!</span>';
    } else {
        // For other languages, return your custom text
        return '<span class="onsale">Custom!</span>';
    }
}
```